# Can I pass inputs to gradle tasks?

Tags: input, gradle

Is it possible to pass inputs to a gradle task? For example, you can pass inputs to a java or a c program. Can I do something similar with a gradle task?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, that you need to pass some value via command line arguments, you can do it like:

```
customTask {
    if ( project.hasProperty("someArg") ) {
        println project.property("someArg")
    }
}
```

Then run your application with this argument

```
gradle customTask -PsomeArg=PassedValue
```

Or you can make a task and get the values on execution phase, like:

```
def username
def password

task getCridentials << {
    def console = System.console()
    if (console) {
        username = console.readLine('username: ')

        password = console.readPassword('password: ')
    } else {
        logger.error "Can't get console."
    }
}
```